# Kineticjs Show Image Based on a id tag

Tags: kineticjs

I am trying to make an interactive plate game demonstrating portion size. I recently came across Kineticjs being able to drag images on a canvas. I have made it where the images are hidden by default but when I add a selector to show images, it will show all images. I set it up where a id is used in the html to call 'show' in the javascript.

1) How would I set this up where it shows the image based on text using an "id" in the html without making several different functions? Does each id need a different tag, like 'showorange'?

```
    document.getElementById('show').addEventListener('click', function() {
        orangeImg.show();
        strawberryImg.show();
        layer.draw();
    }, false);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/m9uq7/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/y53v6/

**Give each list-item a class="food" and an id specific to the name of the food (id="strawberry).**

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" id="papaya" class="food">papaya</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="strawberry" class="food">Strawberry</a></li>
</ul>
```

**That way you can ask the browser to listen for all clicks on the food class**

```
$(".food").click(function(){

    // any item with class="food" was clicked
    // so get the id of the clicked link

    var id=$(this).attr("id");

});
```

**Also give each Kinetic.Image an id specific to the name of the food**

```
// strawberry
var strawberryImg = new Kinetic.Image({
    id:"strawberry",
    image: images.strawberry,
    x: 200,
    y: 55,
    width: 128,
    height: 128,
    draggable: true,
    stroke: 'orange',
    strokeWidth: 5,
    strokeEnabled: false,
    visible: false
});
```

**That way you can ask KineticJS to find the Image with the same name as the clicked html link.**

For example, if the "strawberry" link was clicked you can get the Kinetic strawberry image like this:

```
var node=stage.find("#"+$(this).attr("id"));
node.show();
layer.draw();
```

**So you can respond to a click on any class="food" anchor and show the related image:**

```
$(".food").click(function(){
    var node=stage.find("#"+$(this).attr("id"));
    node.show();
    layer.draw();
    console.log($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I plan on using ~70 images (to make a nutrition plate demonstration). Does this load all images when someone visits the web page or when the user clicks on the link?

Comment: I used your same image loading method so if you add 70 images to the `sources` object then they would all be loaded before the app begins.  :-)

Comment: Hi markE, your answer helps a lot but I am having trouble getting this to work outside of jfiddle. I have included kinetic-v5.0.2.min.js and made sure the script is below the html. When I run in a browser I see "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined" in the developer console. So when I click on the nav option the image doesn't show. Any ideas of why?

Comment: $ means jQuery so include this in your heading also:     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>  I use jquery in my examples to smooth over the many browser incompatibilities (I highly recommend it).  You could easily convert to plain-old-JS using `document.getElementById` and `.click(yourClickHandler)` syntax.  Good luck with your project!